# Vue & Vue Route how to make an image blur when the route begin?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, blur

What i'm trying to do is when you first go to the page that include an slider image it blur I make that done with the following line in mounted() the blur config is an object that run with [v-blur](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-blur) package

```
data(){
   return{
      sliders:{},
      first_slide:'',
      blurConfig: {
           isBlurred: true, // activate and deactivate blur directive example 2
           opacity: 0.2,
           filter: 'blur(1.2px)',
           transition: 'all .3s linear'
       },
    },


 mounted(){
  window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
      self.blurConfig.isBlurred = false
     }, 1000 )
   }
 }
```

But the problem is when I navigate to a different route the code in mounted() will not work because in vue router you only load the page one time and also Updated() will run before it .

```
updated(){
    let self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
    self.blurConfig0.isBlurred = false
 }, 2000 )
```

so I'm stuck I want the image blur when navigate to other route and also when Load the Page

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. watch on router will call whenever your route changes and you also need to call on mounted for first-page load event.

```
watch: {
      $route: function () {
        let self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
    self.blurConfig.isBlurred = false
 }, 2000 )
      }
    },
```

Comment: watch in my component

Comment: it's not working in my component even if Console.log any thing will not work

Comment: It's working on mine. You need to add this to the main page where the actual route serves. watch: {
          $route: function () {
              let self = this;
              setTimeout(function () {
                  console.log("hi")
              }, 2000)
          }
    },